# Matrix multiplication with transpose with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, keras, tensorflow2.0, matrix-multiplication

Trying to do `MatrixMultiplication` in `TF`

```
import tensorflow as tf
a1 = tf.constant(tf.random.normal(shape=(5,4,64)))
tf.matmul(a1,a1,transpose_b=True)
```

This works perfectly fine, but if I `transpose` the input `a1` manually like the following, I get an error:

```
tf.matmul(a1,tf.transpose(a1))
```

Error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: In[0] and In[1] must have compatible batch dimensions: [5,4,64] vs. [64,4,5] [Op:BatchMatMulV2]
```

Documentation:

```
transpose_b: If True, b is transposed before multiplication.
```

So I don't understand the difference, any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute the batch matrix multiplication you need to ensure the following format for the **3D** tensor. Check the [`3-D`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L3174-L3190) tensor matrix multiplication.

```
[batchs, h`, w`] @ [batchs, w``, h``]
```

So, in your above case, it should be

```
import tensorflow as tf

a1 = tf.constant(tf.random.normal(shape=(5,4,64)))

a1.shape, tf.transpose(a1, perm=[0, 2, 1]).shape
(TensorShape([5, 4, 64]), TensorShape([5, 64, 4]))

# swape the height and width - not batch axis 
tf.matmul(a1, tf.transpose(a1, perm=[0, 2, 1])).shape
TensorShape([5, 4, 4])
```